# How do I register two components in root instance using ES6 module system?

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, module, vue-component, es6-modules

I tried about everything but I just can't figure it out. Asking some help from Vue pros :D

```
import calendar_component from "./components/calendar_component.js";
import AKAD from "./ADAKNotes_revamp.js";
import list_component from "./components/list_component.js";


const AKAD_app  = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: [calendar_component, list_component]
});

// [[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <list-comp> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Vue API Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#components), it is one object for `{components }` instead of one array.

So try below codes:

```
const AKAD_app  = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {calendar_component, list_component} 
    // or assign special id for components {'calendar': calendar_component, 'list-comp': list_component}
});
```